# How to use SSL Name Based Vhosts without SNI

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, virtualhost, sni

I need to host a handful of web applications over SSL using name based virtual hosting.

Apache documentation indicates this is possible (https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) if all sites are covered by the SSL certificate.

Is there a way to use one certificate for https traffic to multiple domains like *.foo.com and *.bar.com?

I see that there is a cert called UCC (http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3908/what-is-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate) that appears to do what I am looking for.  Can this be used for my purpose?

Are there other or better alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - a UCC or SAN certificate (two names for the same thing, a cert with subject alternative names configured) will serve your purposes, as it can cover multiple domains without using SNI.  There's no other way to accomplish what you're looking for aside from SNI or just splitting to multiple IP addresses.

For example, see the certificate being served by https://stackexchange.com/.